# recursive lambda and capture (segfault)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

**Compiler**

`g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010`

**Snippet 1** (`&` capture)

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  std::function<void ()> func = [&] () {
    func();
  };
  return 0;
}
```

**Snippet 2** (`func` capture)

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  std::function<void ()> func = [func] () {
    func();
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Both snippets compile but why does running the second result in a segmentation fault?

Comment: The second snippet copies a value that has not been initialized, and thus is not "alive" yet.

Comment: @Alex The function is not called, so it should only create the lambda function, then exit.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah! So using `&func` instead would work because it only copies the address of the lambda function? I didn't understand until now that the capture was *really* like function parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture occurs before the construction of the `std::function`.

So you capture an uninitialized (not even default constructed!) copy of `std::function<void()> func`.  All by itself the capture of the `std::function` is UB (copying a variable before it is constructed!), and invoking it is going to be even "more UB" (invoking a copy of a non-constructed `std::function`!).

The reference case captures a reference to `func`, which is allowed even before it is initialized, so long as it is only used once initialized.

The downside to the reference case is that the lambda only remains valid within the scope of `func`.  A copy of it is also invalid once `func` goes out of scope.  This, in my experience, sucks.

To do a real "full strength" recursive lambda, you need something like a y-combinator.

Here is short a C++14 y-combinator:

```
template<class F>
auto y_combinate( F&& f ) {
  return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args) {
    return f(f, decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

you pass it a lambda that expect a reference to itself as the first argument:

```
std::function<void ()> func = y_combinate( [](auto&& self) {
    self(self);
  }
);
```

and it does the rest.

The y-combinator requirement is because you don't have access to your own `this` within the body of a lambda.  So we add one.

The above y-combinator is only 90%, as it doesn't handle r/l value and const-ness of the function object passed in perfectly.  But it will serve most of the time.

This is a slightly better y-combinate:

```
template<class F>
struct y_combinate_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args)const {
    return f(*this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
template<class F>
y_combinate_t<std::decay_t<F>> y_combinate( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

which makes use a bit better:

```
std::function<void ()> func = y_combinate( [](auto&& self) {
    self();
  }
);
```

the `self` passed in now does not have to be passed `self` itself when invoked.

Comment: How can I use `self` as a `std::function<void()>` (or its equivalent reference) so that I can use it in other functions? Edit: Ah a simple cast worked: `(std::function<void()>&&) self`